# Saved data values not saving correctly on react front end

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring, save

Good afternoon,

For my end project, I created a reminder app where you can add a TaskName, TaskDetails, Date, and Time.
My back end is created with java spring boot and I'm using a MySQL server.
When you add some data into the app it saves it to the database but everything is Null instead of text.
I have looked everywhere for a solution but could not find any.
My guess is I need to convert the text from React to java but this did not work either.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful!

```
import {useState} from "react";

const AddTask = ({onAdd}) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState('')
    const [details, setDetails] = useState('')
    const [day, setDay] = useState('')
    const [time, setTime] = useState('')
    const [reminder, setReminder] = useState(false)
const onSubmit = (e) => {e.preventDefault()
if (!text){
    alert('Please add a task')
    return
}
onAdd({text, day, reminder})
    setText('')
    setDetails('')
    setDay(Date)
    setTime(Date)
    setReminder(false)

}

return(
    <form className='add-form' onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className='form-control'>
            <label>Task</label>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Add Task'
            value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>
        <div className='form-control'>
            <label>Task Details</label>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Add Task Details'
                   value={details} onChange={(e) => setDetails(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>
        <div className='form-control'>
            <label>Day</label>
            <input type='date' placeholder='Add Day'
                   value={day} onChange={(e) => setDay(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>  <div className='form-control'>
        <label>Time</label>
        <input type='time' placeholder='Add Time'
               value={time} onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}/>
    </div>
        <div className='form-control form-control-check'>
            <label>Set Reminder</label>
            <input type='checkbox'
                   checked={reminder}
                   value={reminder} onChange={(e) => setReminder(e.currentTarget.checked)}/>
        </div>

        <input type='Submit' value='save Task'
        className='btn btn-block' />
    </form>
```

Thank you in advance!

Here are some pictures:
[image]
[image: Front end]

[image: Server][[image: App adding a Task][3]]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a state for each element of your form, you can create a single object and change it's values when you need. Here is my approach.

```
// Create a empty object to use on hook
const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
   task: '',
   details: ''
})
const [formData, updateFormData] = useState(initialFormData)
```

On your form inputs change your onChange to update state form data:

```
<TextField
   type="text"
   name="task"
   label="Task..."
   onChange={e => updateFormData({ ...formData, task: e.target.value })}
 />
```

And on your submit function you can get values by acessing state objects:

```
const onSubmit = e -> {
   e.preventDefault()
   console.log(formData.task)
}
```

Comment: I tried doing it your way but it did not work at all, maybe I understood you wrong.